# Actual Twilio video bitrate not matching the maxVideoBitrate set

Tags: video, twilio, twilio-api, videochat, vp8

I am using twilio to build a video chat app. I am setting the maxVideoBitrate as follows:

```
  navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
        audio: true,
        video: {width: 320}
    })
        .then(function (mediaStream) {
            console.log('mediaStream');
            console.log(mediaStream);
            console.log(mediaStream.getTracks());

            var connectOptions = {
                name: roomName,
                logLevel: 'off',
                tracks: mediaStream.getTracks(),
                maxAudioBitrate: 16000,
                maxVideoBitrate: 64000,
            };
            return Video.connect(data.token, connectOptions);
        })
        .then(roomJoined, function (error) {
            log('Could not connect to Twilio: ' + error.message);
        });
```

The bit-rate of the sent video doesn't seem to match value set using maxVideoBirate.( verified using webrtc-internals).

Here is the chart from webrtc internals with maxVideoBitrate set to 6400.

[image]

With maxVideoBitrate set to 64000.

[image]

Comment: From the graphs, it looks like Twilio may be interpreting the params as bytes per second as opposed to bits per second (so 51.2 kbit/s for `6400` and 512 kbit/s for `64000`).

Comment: It shoots well above 600k in the second graph. If twilio was infact interpreting the params in bytes, this shouldn't happen right? And according to the docs, the parameter's name is maxVideo**Bit**rate.

Comment: From what I remember seeing, brief overshoots/spikes could happen. Yes, both the docs and the parameter's name indicate bits per second; my point is that it could be a bug in Twilio's interpretation of the parameter's value.

Comment: Can I check that you're now using Twilio Video 1.3.0 or above?

Comment: I am using the Javascript SDK at version 1.6.1

Comment: @philnash, Any updates on this?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I've followed this up with the video team internally. We were wondering whether you were using a group room or a peer to peer room? How many people are in the room too?

Comment: Peer to peer rooms with two participants.